# NullPointerException When Reading Text File

Tags: java, arraylist, nullpointerexception, null, text-files

I have created a constructor that takes in a .txt file name and print the data in it as an ArrayList.

```
public class rrr {

  private String filename;

  public rrr(String afilename){
  afilename=filename;
  }
  public void readdtata() throws IOException  {
    FileReader p1=new FileReader(filename);
    BufferedReader p2=new BufferedReader(p1);
    ArrayList<String> data=new ArrayList<String>();
    String line;

    while((line=p2.readLine()) != null){
     data.add(line);
    }

    p2.close();

    for(int i=0;i<data.size();i++){
     System.out.println(data.get(i));
    }
  }
}
```

when trying to test it I get these errors
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

```
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:116)

at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:79)

at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:41)

at rrr.readdtata(rrr.java:14)

at testin.main(testin.java:17)
```

does anyone have an Idea about how to solve this problem please.

Comment: You will need to learn the general concepts of how to debug a NPE (NullPointerException). **You should critically read your exception's stacktrace to find the line of code at fault, the line that throws the exception, and then inspect that line carefully**, find out which variable is null, and then trace back into your code to see why. You will run into these again and again, trust me.

Comment: Note that your question title is incorrect as you're in fact doing no file reading in any constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your constructor I believe it should be:

```
public rrr(String afilename){
   this.filename = afilename;
}
```

Comment: You forgot the `this`. I have edited your answer to supply it. But good pick up -- his constructor was not setting the class field correctly. 1+